# Detect the minimum permissions PHP needs to write to a directory: 0777, 0770 or 0700?

Tags: php, permissions, detect

Imagine some script & its folders was uploaded with FTP. Usually, the folder permissions are wrong and the script should suggest which permissions to set. Certainly, it's not good to set 0777 for everything I'm going to write to. But there're 3 possible webserver configurations:

1. PHP user = user FTP. Thus, writing needs 0700
2. The user is different, but it belongs to the same group. It's 0770
3. PHP runs from `nobody` or there's no common GID: it's 0777

Is there a way to detect what permissions octets are enough for the script to function?

The PCNTL extension is not welcome because some configurations lack it.

Comment: "It's not possible to create a test file/dir because we can never know whether the directory is even functional." What's that supposed to mean? Are you not aware of the directories that exist in your website?

Comment: A typo :) The idea was to create a test file with 0777 perms and check what comes of it. Then, chmod it to 0777 and so on. Ugly, but possible :)

Comment: Isn't it easier to set everything non-writeable, except a few directories you *know* you are going to write to?

Comment: That is. However, for directories, I should detect whether I should use 0777, or 0770 | 0700 will be enough. Too much permissions are not good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`posix_access()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-access.php)